# Uploading a File in a flexdashboard

Tags: r, input, flexdashboard

I am trying to add an input file in a flexdashboard, but I am a little confused. Previously I created a function to generate a plot, and then I call the function renderPlot with the function in order to get the plot in the dashboard.

[R flexdashboard and shiny interactive plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854898/r-flexdashboard-and-shiny-interactive-plot)

But now, If I create a function to read the file I don´t understand how to call it.

How to follow the same idea, create a function that read a file with an input file in the dashboard and then perform the analysis in the dashboard.

I have generated this code

````
    ---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```{r, echo = FALSE}
fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv"))


```
````

With this I have obtained a side bar with the File Input. but how to use that uploaded file in any analysis and show the results in the dashboard?

[image]

````
    ---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```{r, echo = FALSE}
fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv"))
df_reac <- reactive({
  read_xlsx(file1$datapath)
})

```

Column{data-width=300}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```{r, echo = FALSE}
renderTable(df_reac)


```
````

Comment: Please post the code to the function in question, as well as the rendering, and UI

Comment: Done¡ I dont have UI because I am using flexdashboard. It seems that it is easy for basic dashboards.

Comment: In the server call the file by using `data<-read.csv(file1$datapath)` and then you can use `data` however you want. Reactive environments are going to play a role here so make sure you read up on those.

Comment: I am not sure about what is the server, because the flexdashboard only uses one file. this is the server ?

Comment: Sorry, disregard the part about the server. Read the data into r Global

Comment: what do you mean with datapath? is all the words of "C:/...."?

Comment: I did it, but I can´t get the right solution:

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but this code will let you upload files on Flexdashboard:

````
    ---
    title: "Untitled"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: columns
        vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    ```

    ```{r}
    dataset <- eventReactive(input$file1,{
      dataset <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    })
    ```

    # Column {.sidebar}

    ```{r, echo = FALSE}
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                    multiple = TRUE,
                    accept = c("text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".csv"))
    ```

    # Data 

    ## Row

    ### Table 1 - Show the data recently acquired

    ```{r}
    renderTable({
      dataset <- dataset()
      dataset
    })
    ```
````

The main issue was to create a reactive function, since you don't know about the dataset until you upload the file. The reactive value is `input$file1`