# can you manipulate an uploaded file in flexdashboard

Tags: r, io, flexdashboard

Following on from [Uploading a File in a flexdashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112979/uploading-a-file-in-a-flexdashboard), is it possible to assign the read file  to a variable and perform actions on it

Currently, I would do this to view the uploaded file:

```
dataset1 <- eventReactive(input$file1,{
  dataset <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
})

fileInput("file1", "Upload Data Sheet",
                    multiple = TRUE,
                    accept = c("text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".csv"))

renderTable({
  dataset1()
  
})
```

I tried to assign it to an object that can be manipulated like a dataframe with:

```
z = renderTable({
  dataset1()
  
})

dim(z) # or z %>% filter(...) or z %>% mutate(new = 5) ...
```

But end up with error saying `no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('shiny.render.function', 'function')"`

This makes me think that I cannot manipulate an uploaded file.

Is this the case, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But `z` is not the dataset itself, is just a shiny output created from it.

You can manipulate the data inside the reactive function, e.g.:

```
z <- renderTable({
  dataset1() %>%
    dim()
})
```